# Visual studio 2015 CE intellisense keeps closing up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have quite an odd issue in VS 2015 CE. I'm working on a ASP MVC site and when I I try to access **Model properties** using Razor in view **inside a method** a visual studio immediately closes the intellisense window which shows the available properties.

Works perfectly:

```
@Model.Shared.UserName
```

Doesn't work

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Shared.UserName)
```

When I'm typing the "Model." inside a method, Visual studio keeps closing up the suggestion window. This is becoming really annoying. Has anyone experienced something similar?

The window I'm referring to: [image: here]

Comment: I've been experiencing this, too.  The IntelliSense window popups and then closes just as quickly.

Comment: For me this is only happening when using extension methods.  Very weird.

Comment: same here. Really annoying

Comment: rrrr , me to. im using Enterprise after a clean system install

Comment: Another raised hand. I'm using Visual Studio Update 3, downloaded a month ago. I've been experiencing this annoyance all the time.
To clarify - after pressing Ctrl + space it does open and does stay open but I need to do this almost every time.

Comment: Use ReSharper and you will be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround that I've managed to satisfy myself with after half a year is to use **ReSharper** which amazingly fixed this issue as well. It's not exactly solution to why the Visual studio is acting this way, but there is probably little left to do.

Comment: I am using Resharper and having the same issue, can you list some settings that you are using? I am not sure why I am still getting this issue.

Comment: Nevermind, sorted it out. Even while using Resharper I was still relying on Visual Studio's Intellisense which was broken.

Comment: Downvoted due to reccomending a paid app. What about those of us that can't afford it. Also, doesn't answer the question specifically about how to fix intellisense itself. More of a work around.

Comment: Mate, it's my question from 5 years ago that I answered myself. I also specifically say in the answer that it's a 'workaround'. There was probably a bug in VS at that time and ReSharper worked just fine. Your comment is an absolute waste of time and effort.